# Python Group by Bucketing

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to rank the following df based on the Sharpe grouped by Year/Month. For instance , in January 2018, I would like to look at the Sharpe’s for Stock 1,2,3 with the values of 0.4,0.3 and 0.6 respectively and rank them between the scale of 1 (low score) – 5(highest score).
My criteria would be if the if Sharpe Ratio greater than 2,assign a score of 5, if Sharpe Lower than -0.5 then assign score of 1, if Sharpe in between -0 .5 and 2, use the linear increments to compute the Sharpe score.

```
Year    Month   Stock   Sharpe
2018    1   Stock 1 0.4
2018    1   Stock 2 0.3
2018    1   Stock 3 0.6
2018    2   Stock 1 0.2
2018    2   Stock 2 0.3
2018    2   Stock 3 0.5
2018    3   Stock 1 -0.2
2018    3   Stock 2 1.5
2018    3   Stock 3 0.7
```

When I type this code, I get the following error:

```
df.groupby(['Year','Month'])[['Sharpe]].apply(lambda x:1 if (x <= -0.5) else 1)
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Any thoughts on this?
Thank you

Comment: does the grouping matter at all for the assigned ranking? It sounds like the "rank" is a simple score that follows *score = max(1,min(1.8+1.6*sharpe,5))*

Comment: yes grouping matters as I would like to do it for each month hence the rank of the stocks can change. For instance when switching from 2nd to 3rd month, the score of the Stock 1 should go from .. to 1.

Comment: Can you write down the desired rank values for the example above (for all nine rows)? I don't understand the connection between the ranking and the [-0.5 to 2] rule.

Answer (score 0):

Looked at your requirement rather than specific approach.  Key point `apply()` on a `groupby()` gives a dataframe so `lambda` function needs to operate on a dataframe which is subset of data defined by `groupby()`

1. generate a larger test dataset
2. `assign()` a column to take the result
3. `pd.cut()` is really the core of what you want.  Continuous variable that you want to put into bins
4. get bins from `value_counts()`. then modify them to meet the requirement. NB `bins=4` is one less than required bins as boundaries are being inserted by code
5. there is a possibility this lands with duplicate bin boundaries hence `duplicates="drop"`

```py
a = [[e for e in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])

a = np.array(np.meshgrid([2018], [1,2], 
                     [f"Stock {i+1}" for i in range(15)],
                    )).reshape(3,-1)
a = [a[0], a[1], a[2], [round(random.uniform(-1,2.5),1) for e in a[0]]]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":a[0], "Month":a[1], "Stock":a[2], "Sharpe":a[3]})
df["Sharpe"] = df["Sharpe"].astype(float)

def myrank(df):
    # given boundaries get bins between boundaries
    b = sorted([i.left 
                for i in df[df["Sharpe"].between(-0.5,2)]["Sharpe"]\
                .value_counts(bins=4).index])
    b[0] = -0.5 # rank 1 only goues to =< -0.5
    b[-1] = 2 # rank 5 only goes to > 2
    b += [-100,200]  # add in lower and upper bounds
    df["Rank"] = pd.cut(df["Sharpe"], sorted(b), labels=[i+1 for i in range(len(b)-1)],
                       duplicates="drop")
    return df
df = df.assign(Rank=1).groupby(["Year","Month"]).apply(lambda df: myrank(df))

print(df.sort_values(["Year","Month","Sharpe"]).to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
 Year Month     Stock  Sharpe Rank
 2018     1   Stock 1    -1.0    1
 2018     1  Stock 15    -0.7    1
 2018     1  Stock 13    -0.2    2
 2018     1   Stock 4    -0.1    2
 2018     1   Stock 3     0.3    2
 2018     1   Stock 2     0.4    3
 2018     1  Stock 11     0.4    3
 2018     1   Stock 9     0.5    3
 2018     1  Stock 14     0.8    3
 2018     1  Stock 12     1.0    4
 2018     1  Stock 10     1.7    4
 2018     1   Stock 8     1.8    4
 2018     1   Stock 5     1.9    4
 2018     1   Stock 7     1.9    4
 2018     1   Stock 6     2.3    5
 2018     2   Stock 9    -0.8    1
 2018     2  Stock 13    -0.8    1
 2018     2  Stock 15     0.1    2
 2018     2  Stock 14     0.3    2
 2018     2   Stock 7     0.5    3
 2018     2   Stock 1     0.6    3
 2018     2  Stock 10     0.6    3
 2018     2  Stock 12     1.0    4
 2018     2   Stock 3     1.2    4
 2018     2   Stock 2     1.3    4
 2018     2   Stock 4     1.3    4
 2018     2   Stock 8     1.3    4
 2018     2   Stock 6     1.4    4
 2018     2  Stock 11     2.3    5
 2018     2   Stock 5     2.4    5
```